# django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet with Django pytest

Tags: django, pytest, django-testing, pytest-django, django-mixer

I'm writing test for my `Django 2.0` application.

I am using `mixer` and the directory structure is like

```
project
|- src
   |- contacts
      |- migrations
      |- tests
         |- __init__.py
         |- test_models.py
      |- __init__.py
      |- models.py
      |- apps.py
   |- koober                  <----   (main app)
      |- settings
         |- __init__.py
         |- local.py
         |- production.py
      |- __init__.py
      |- test_settings.py
      |- urls.py
      |- wsgi.py
   |- .coveragerc
   |- manage.py
   |- pytest.ini
|- other_files
|- not_related_to_project
|- Pipfile
|- Pipfile.lock
|- Procfile
```

When I run from `project` directory

```
project$ pipenv run py.test
```

It gives error as

```
============================================================================= test session starts ==============================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.6.5, pytest-3.6.1, py-1.5.3, pluggy-0.6.0
rootdir: /home/anuj/code/python/koober, inifile:
plugins: django-3.3.0, cov-2.5.1
collected 0 items / 1 errors                                                                                                                                                   

==================================================================================== ERRORS ====================================================================================
______________________________________________________________ ERROR collecting src/contacts/tests/test_models.py ______________________________________________________________
src/contacts/tests/test_models.py:2: in <module>
    from mixer.backend.django import mixer
../../../.local/share/virtualenvs/koober-MOd9u5HA/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mixer/backend/django.py:11: in <module>
    from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey, GenericRelation   # noqa
../../../.local/share/virtualenvs/koober-MOd9u5HA/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/fields.py:3: in <module>
    from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
../../../.local/share/virtualenvs/koober-MOd9u5HA/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/models.py:134: in <module>
    class ContentType(models.Model):
../../../.local/share/virtualenvs/koober-MOd9u5HA/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py:100: in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
../../../.local/share/virtualenvs/koober-MOd9u5HA/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py:244: in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
../../../.local/share/virtualenvs/koober-MOd9u5HA/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py:127: in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
E   django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 errors during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
=========================================================================== 1 error in 0.31 seconds ============================================================================
```

When I run the same command from `project/src` file, it gives error as

```
ImportError: No module named 'koober.test_settings.py'; 'koober.test_settings' is not a package
```

I checked for any error with

```
project$ pipenv run python src/manage.py check
```

and it gives

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
```

even `pipenv run python src/manage.py runserver` is working fine.

content of **test_settings.py**

```
from koober.settings import *

DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.sqlite3",
        "NAME": ":memory:",
    }
}

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.locmem.EmailBackend'
```

> Updated test_settings.py

```
import os

import django

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "koober.settings")
django.setup()

DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.sqlite3",
        "NAME": ":memory:",
    }
}

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.locmem.EmailBackend'
```

**contents of pytest.ini**

```
[pytest]

DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = koober.test_settings.py
addopts = --nomigrations --cov=. --cov-report=html
```

**contents of src/contacts/tests/test_models.py**

```
import pytest
from mixer.backend.django import mixer

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

pytestmark = pytest.mark.django_db


class TestContact:
    def test_model(self):
        user = mixer.blend(User)
```

Also, can see in pytest log, **pytest.ini** file is not detected when running `pytest` or `py.test` and **inifile:** is empty

> Edit 3: What works for me

**updated test_settings.py**

```
from .settings import *

DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.sqlite3",
        "NAME": ":memory:",
    }
}

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.locmem.EmailBackend'
```

command running from `/src` directory

```
pipenv run pytest --ds=koober.test_settings
```

Comment: Do you have an `__init__.py` file in `koober` dir?

Comment: yes, there is `__init__.py` in `koober` app

Comment: First of all: running `pytest` from `project/` dir will not find any tests because you didn't give `pytest` any hint where to look for tests; either move `pytest.ini` up to `project` dir to indicate the roodir, or pass it explicitly: `pipenv run pytest --rootdir=src/`.

Comment: Second: `koober.test_settings.py` in your `pytest.ini` looks wrong. It must be the module name same as if you would import it from code, so I guess `koober.test_settings`, without the file ext. Also, test if the settings module is importable from where you run the tests: does `pipenv run python -c "import koober.test_settings" ` work or is an `ImportError` raised?

Comment: running `pipenv run python -c "import koober.test_settings"` from `project` directory is giving `ImportError` but running same from `src` directory is working fine. I also, tried `--rootdir=src/` but still getting same error. running `pipenv run pytest --rootdir=src/` gives a line in error log `rootdir: /Users/anuj/code/PyCharm/koober-py/src, inifile:` You can see `inifile:` is empty. It is not detecting `pytest.ini` file

Comment: I run `pipenv run pytest --rootdir=src/ --ds=koober.test_settings` from `project` directory and it gives `ImportError: No module named 'koober'`

Comment: I tried running `pipenv run pytest --ds=koober.test_settings` from `src` directory and not it is giving `raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")`

Comment: @hoefling please see `Edit 3` This configuration works for me. But I need to `cd src` and include `test_settings.py` in `--ds=` flag. `pytest.ini` is still not detecting.

Comment: Run `pipenv run pytest src/` then. `pytest` will not descend into subdirs looking for ini files; see [Finding the `rootdir`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/customize.html#finding-the-rootdir) for the behaviour. Or move `pytest.ini` into `project/` dir to be able to invoke `pipenv run pytest` without needing to pass additional args.

Comment: Also, since you can't import `koober.test_settings` from `project/` dir, you have to adjust the `sys.path` - either pass it via `PYTHONPATH` env var, e.g. `PYTHONPATH=src/ pipenv run pytest`, or add an empty `conftest.py` file to `src/` dir to let `pytest` handle this.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but it might seem that your test is not importing the django application along with its settings properly.
Best way to emulate that is to include(import) whatever is there in manage.py,( whether you need to incude get wsgi application is a different debate) before your script. I have no experience with mixer but error looks like the django application is not being loaded in proper sequence.

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41826771/2138792) for the syntax.
Importantly give correct path here

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", correctpath)
```

Also give the correct settings path i.e. make sure settings have all the neccesary stuff like installed apps and all other stuff like db conf to make it work and even if it doesnt have so u can  import the missing ones from the working settings file like your local or production ones.

Comment: please check updated `test_settings.py` file. I have added `setdefaul` but still getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your **INSTALLED_APPS** problem misconfiguration of this attribute, or you not at your app label at your app.py in your apps

Answer (score 0):

In my case, after upgrading to Django 1.11, this started mysteriously happening. The solution was to use pytest's `--ds` parameter to tell pytest where to find our django settings. So our command went from:

```
pytest path/to/some/test.py
```

To:

```
pytest --ds proj.settings path/to/some/test.py
```

Weird, but fine, now it works.