# Django: Unknown command: 'collectstatic' when using call_command

Tags: python, django, manage.py, collectstatic

I have a Django project with `"django.contrib.staticfiles"` in `INSTALLED_APPS`. Therefore, I can run `./manage.py collectstatic`. But I need to use [call_command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/django-admin/#running-management-commands-from-your-code).

Running `python -c 'from django.core.management import call_command; call_command("collectstatic")'` results in `django.core.management.base.CommandError: Unknown command: 'collectstatic'`

What am I doing wrong? Shouldn't the 2 commands be absolutely identical? Obviously, environments, paths, etc are correct in both cases. I am running both commands from the same shell in a docker container.

Comment: Do you have the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable set? Also I see you haven't called `django.setup()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django Standalone Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39723310/django-standalone-script)

Comment: Why not `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE='myproj.settings' python -m 'django' collectstatic`?

Comment: DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is set. correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe running `./manage.py collectstatic` would not work either if it wasn't?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I'm trying to run the above commands in a ready built docker container where django works correctly. The test suite passes, API calls to the container function as expected. I don't think there's anything wrong about `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`, like in the question which you have linked. Or any need to call `django.setup()`.

Comment: @Gerry no my question is whether you have set the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable or not. You should set it if you haven't (`manage.py` has a line that does this usually). Django uses that to find the settings to be used (And hence discovers the apps to be installed). You should also call `django.setup()` for the same purpose.

Comment: Also why can this particular script of yours not be a [custom management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/custom-management-commands/)?

Comment: It could be, and for the lack of a better solution it probably will. Nonetheless, for my understanding, why is my `call_command` wrong?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat indeed, calling `django.setup()` seems to have solved it. For everyone else struggling to find the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/settings/#calling-django-setup-is-required-for-standalone-django-usage DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE was already set. If you wish to post this in an answer I'll be happy to accept it. Thank you

Comment: I see my previous linked question wasn't a great canonical. This one here should answer your question: [How to execute external script in the Django environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41825037/how-to-execute-external-script-in-the-django-environment)